# Uninstalling or removing KMail

Tags: gnome, uninstall, kmail

I am somewhat new to Linux, but not a total noob. I recently installed Kmail on my ubuntu 17.10 os from Ubuntu Software. Nothing wrong with it, but I use something else for now. I uninstalled it as usual. 
However, now I see it has left some other little programs or applets or .dll's or whatever they are called, and show up in my Applications overview. I cant remove them using Ubuntu software as when I search for them on the software program it returns no results.
The 'programs' are CONTACT PRINT THEME EDITOR; CONTACT THEME EDITOR; KMAIL HEADER THEME EDITOR; KSIEVE EDITOR; 
Here are screenshots of these programs... I just want to remove them from my system but they don't go away even after reboot and they clutter up the system menus!! Please help!! Perhaps by using the terminal I can remove them but How?
[screenshot of the leftover stuff](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbxUc.png)

Answer (score 1):

When uninstalling a program from linux, remove will remove the core program, purge will remove the program and the misc data files and garbage you no longer need if you're not going to use it, but might want to keep if you were just installing another version, and autoremove will clean up files that are no longer needed after the removal of applications.

So first purge the application

```
sudo apt-get purge <application>
```

then autoremove stuff that's no longer needed.

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```